# jQuery 1.4.2 built in tab functionality?

Tags: jquery

Ingoring all aspects of design, with base jQuery 1.4.2 NOT jQuery UI, is there any kind of radio class or tab functionality?  I can't find what I'm looking for on Google.

**update**

I'm not looking for UI elements, only the functionality of tabs.

By [radio class](http://www.sencha.com/products/core/docs/source/Element.style.html#method-Ext.Element-radioClass) I'm referring to ExtJS where you can have a `ul` list of elements.  Creating a "radio class" means that only one of the `li` elements can have that class at a time.  It's a great way of doing tabs.

Comment: What do you mean by `radio class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.
You need to use or create a plugin.

In general, the base jQuery library contains basic utilities and animations, but does not include any UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tab functionality built into the jQuery core (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs)

If you google "jQuery tab plugins" you'll find several non-Jquery UI plugins that work just fine.

You could also roll your own. There are plenty of tutorials out there: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-tabs/